# how to set android style text input in kivy?

Tags: kivy

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEt15QIH-n8) he design the textinput animation or something I've no idea what exactly he had done. when the textinput got focus a blue colored line got focus and the hint text also. how to achieve this in kivy textinput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App in video is written using [KivyMD](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD) module that provides set of "material design" (being using in Android and other Google products) widgets.

Installation instructions are [here](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD#installation-and-use-with-buildozer). And [here](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/120#note_51962945) is simple example of usage.

Comment: Is there a way to do so without using KVMD? I tried that module and found out it is too slow to use in single core ARM processor.

Comment: @BerryMan KivyMD isn't slow itself. Most slow part of kivy is widget creation. If you delay creating widgets as much as possible using KivyMD should be ok. Answering your question: there's no ready-to-use way other than KivyMD as far as I know.

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov It might not be slow in PC, but it is very slow in micro-computer with touch screen. The main reason why I use kivy to develop is because it supports multi-touch and python language to create GUI. However, whenever kivy performs animations, it gets really slow, and KVMD contains a lot of animations. That's probably why,